# How to predict sentiment analysis using Keras imdb dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using keras to implement sentiment analysis model. I'v created the model and trained it. but now i'm not sure how to predict new data since the imdb dataset is already in vectors([22,33,4, etc...]).

so how do i preform a prediction to a new sentence like: "i love this movie"?

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM, Convolution1D, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

# Using keras to load the dataset with the top_words
top_words = 10000
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)

# Pad the sequence to the same length
max_review_length = 1600
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)

# Using embedding from Keras
embedding_vecor_length = 300
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))

# Convolutional model (3x conv, flatten, 2x dense)
model.add(Convolution1D(64, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Convolution1D(32, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Convolution1D(16, 3, padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(180,activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

# Log to tensorboard
tensorBoardCallback = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', write_graph=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, callbacks=[tensorBoardCallback], batch_size=64)

# Evaluation on the test set
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))

model.save("trained_demo.h5")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to get the dictionary of word, index pairs. Using that you can convert words to indexes, finally pad it.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
word2index = imdb.get_word_index()
test=[]
for word in word_tokenize( "i love this movie"):
     test.append(word2index[word])

test=sequence.pad_sequences([test],maxlen=max_review_length)
model.predict(test)
```

Comment: How can I get this "word_tokenize" in the for statement you have shown? I tried to define in this way. "from keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer import word_tokenize". It did not work for me. How can I define "word_tokenize" Could you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

In order to study this topic, I wrote a machine learning that works on keras.
The machine classifies reviews for new movies from the site
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8579674/reviews?ref_=tt_urv
based on IMDB database.

```py
    import numpy as np
    from keras import models
    from keras import layers
    from keras.datasets import imdb
    from nltk import word_tokenize
    import string
    
    TOP_WORDS = 10000
    
    def Preparing_string(text_string, dimension = TOP_WORDS):
        text_string = text_string.lower()
        table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(string.punctuation))
        text_string = text_string.translate(table)
    
        word2index = imdb.get_word_index()
        test=[]
        for word in word_tokenize(text_string):
            test.append(word2index[word])
    
        results = np.zeros(dimension)
        for _ , sequence in enumerate(test):
            if sequence < dimension:
                results[sequence] = 1
    
        print("\nOriginal string:", text_string,"\n")
        print("\nIndex conversion:", test,"\n")
        results = np.reshape(results,(1, TOP_WORDS))
        print("\nConvert to vectors:", results,"\n")
        return results
    
    def vectorize(sequences, dimension = TOP_WORDS):
        results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
        for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
            results[i, sequence] = 1
        return results
    
    (training_data, training_targets), (testing_data, testing_targets) = imdb.load_data(num_words=TOP_WORDS)
    data = np.concatenate((training_data, testing_data), axis=0)
    targets = np.concatenate((training_targets, testing_targets), axis=0)
    
    data = vectorize(data)
    targets = np.array(targets).astype("float32")
    test_x = data[:10000]
    test_y = targets[:10000]
    train_x = data[10000:]
    train_y = targets[10000:]

    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation = "relu", input_shape=(TOP_WORDS, )))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
    model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
    model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"))
    model.summary()

    model.compile(
                optimizer = "adam",
                loss = "binary_crossentropy",
                metrics = ["accuracy"]
                )
    
    results = model.fit(
                        train_x, train_y,
                        epochs= 10,
                        batch_size = 500,
                        validation_data = (test_x, test_y)
                        )
    
    print("Test-loss:", results.history["loss"])
    print("Test-Accuracy:", results.history["accuracy"])
        
    data_string = Preparing_string("First off, this is NOT a war film. It is a movie about the bond of men in war. It is by far the best movie I've seen in a very, very long time. I had high expectations and was not disappointed. At first I was eager to see the one shot idea Sam Mendes went into this with but, after awhile, I stopped paying attention to that. While everything about the movie was well done I was so caught up in the two central characters that nothing else mattered. I will watch this again and again.")
    print("predict:",model.predict(data_string))
    print("predict_classes:",model.predict_classes(data_string))
    print("------1 is Good-------\n")
    data_string = Preparing_string("One of the best films I've seen in a long while. Worth seeing on a big screen. Cinematography is outstanding, the one shot process really makes you feel as though you are there. The two leading actors really grasped the concept that human contact can be so strong, especially in such awful situations as war. Insightful, moving and an overall amazing watch.")
    print("predict:",model.predict(data_string))
    print("predict_classes:",model.predict_classes(data_string))
    print("------1 is Good-------\n")
    data_string = Preparing_string("I felt dirty, I felt tired, I felt hungry, I felt a will to succeed and I felt sadness when I was watching the movie. It felt like I was also fighting to reach Colonel MacKenzie for two hours. Several hours later after my emotions are still outside my body. Fantastic photo and music. Good casting of staff. The movie is just perfect!")
    print("predict:",model.predict(data_string))
    print("predict_classes:",model.predict_classes(data_string))
    print("------1 is Good-------\n")
    data_string = Preparing_string("I don't feel like I know the characters at all. I have no idea why the two soldiers were friends or what they had been through together. The cinematography tried so hard to make this an emotional shocking movie that it had the opposite effect. War scenes with gratuitous up close views of corpses and body parts that don't add anything to the story got old quick.")
    print("predict:",model.predict(data_string))
    print("predict_classes:",model.predict_classes(data_string))
    print("------0 is Bad-------\n")
    data_string = Preparing_string("Predictable and horrendous. The acting was terrible and the story was common and nonsense. The only exciting part about the movie was the very end when finally people were dying and it represented WW1. I highly doubt he met a strange woman with an abandoned child and I highly doubt any of this even happened. This movie was Saving Private Ryan, but boring and predictable.")
    print("predict:",model.predict(data_string))
    print("predict_classes:",model.predict_classes(data_string))
    print("------0 is Bad-------\n")
```

This image shows an example of the program output
[image]